# PHP Probability Distribution function

Tags: php, statistics, probability

Does anyone know a function for probability distribution?

Say I have an array:

```
$arr = array(
    'A' => 100, 
    'B' => 200, 
    'C' => 300, 
    'D' => 400
);
```

I am looking for the function to output something like A=97, B=203,C=312,D=388 without having to do 1000 iterations. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the array is $image,
$Lg is the number of the discrete possible values

```
    $n_element=count($image);
    $cdf_array=array_fill(0,$Lg,0);
    for($i=0;$i<$n_element;$i++){
        $cdf_array[$image[$i]-1]=$cdf_array[$image[$i]-1]+1;
    }
    $cdf_array=array_filter($cdf_array,function($var){return $var!=0;});
    $keys=array_keys($cdf_array);
    $cdf_min=$cdf_array[$keys[0]];

    $not_null_el=count($keys);
    for($i=0;$i<$not_null_el;$i++){
        $cdf_array[$keys[$i]]=array_sum(array_chunk($cdf_array,$i+1,1)[0]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Someone did this before. Follow the tut, it helped me out.

heres my take from it:

```
<?php
class WeightedRandom
{
    private $generated;
    private $weights;
    private $items;

    public function __construct( array $weights, array $items  )
    {

        $this->weights = $weights;
        $this->items = $items;

    }

    public function RandomNumber( int $min, int $max )
    {
        return mt_rand() * ( $max - $min ) + $max;
    }

    public function Generate()
    {
        $totalWeight = array_sum( $this->weights );
        $randomNum = $this->RandomNumber(0, $totalWeight);
        $weightSum = 0;
        $itemCount = count($this->items);
        $item;
        $i;

        for ( $i = 0; $i < $itemCount; $i++ ) 
        {
            $weightSum += $this->weights[$i];

            if ( $randomNum <= $weightSum )
            {
                $item = $this->items[$i];
                break;
            }
        }

        return $item;

    }

    /*
    public function Generate()
    {
        $weightedList = [];
        $multiples;
        $i;
        $j;
        $weightCount;

        for( $i = 0; $i < $weightCount; $i++ )
        {
            $multiples = $this->weights[$i] * 10;

            for( $j = 0; $j < $multiples; $j++)
            {
                array_push($weightedList, $this->items[$i]);
            }
        }

        return $weightedList;
    }
    */
}
?>
```

[Source and tutorial](http://codetheory.in/weighted-biased-random-number-generation-with-javascript-based-on-probability/)

Comment: While this answer may theoretically answer the question, [it is better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/237685) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The tutorial is educational for him/her to follow because two methods are employed and it's in js not php. Do I do all the work for him/her or let him follow a tut and implement it him/her self?

Comment: Updated it. Really down votes? Didn't see any of you post an answer yourselves.

Comment: Sorry but this code only returns 1 item. I am looking for all the items returned without having to do 1000 iterations.

Comment: You can't avoid several iterations. It will only do the calculation once for any given set. To my knowledge you can get the effect you want with out iterations for any given set.